# varnish - vcl rule to enable esi only for logged in users

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I want to enable esi only for logged in users. Logged out users should be served whole page through cache.

I wrote below vcl for this. Problem with this is that once it caches page for logged in or for logged out, it displays the same to all.

```
vcl_recv {
      if (req.http.Cookie ~ "loggedIn") {
                if (req.url ~ "^/esi")
                {
                        return (pass);
                }
                if (req.url ~ "page"){
                        return (lookup);
                }
                return (pipe);
        }
        return (lookup);
}
sub vcl_pipe {
        set bereq.http.connection = "close";
}
sub vcl_fetch {
               if (req.url ~ "page"){
                        set beresp.do_esi = true;
                        set beresp.ttl = 1d;
                        return (deliver);
                }
                set beresp.ttl = 1d;
                return (deliver);
}
```

One solution seems is using vcl_hash on combination of url and LoggedIn cookie that has two values 0 or 1. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to detect the cookie and get its value
2. Then you have to pass the request in vcl_recv & vcl_fetch.When the logged in cookie is present.
3. You can check this in two ways like checking cookie value or by checking logged in cookie is set
4. I am giving the answer by using cookie value as below

   ```
   sub identify_cookie{
       #Call cookie based detection method in vcl_recv
       if (req.http.cookie ~ "loggedIn=") {
           set req.http.loggedIn = regsub(req.http.cookie, "(.*?)(loggedIn=)([^;]*)(.*)$", "\3");
       }
   }

   sub vcl_recv {
      call identify_cookie; #Used to get identify cookie and get its value
      if(req.http.loggedIn && req.url ~ "^/esi"){
       #used to get value using cookie value
       return (pass);
      }
      if (req.url !~ "wp-(login|admin)" && req.http.Cookie !~ "loggedIn"){
        #remove all the request cookie(s) except loggedIn and check for wordpress admin
        unset req.http.Cookie;
      }
   }

   sub vcl_fetch {
       if(req.http.loggedIn && req.url ~ "^/esi") {
          return (hit_for_pass);
       }
       if (req.url !~ "wp-(login|admin)" && beresp.http.set-Cookie !~ "loggedIn"){
            #remove all the response cookie(s) except loggedIn and check for wordpress admin
           unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
       }
   }
   ```